# How to create a NSObject class in iOS

Tags: ios7, nsobject

I need to get some large amount of data from a web service,, It has a `JSON` format. so I created a `NSObject` class to assign every object's properties. Im thinking to get that `JSON` data into a `NSMutableArray` and then using a for loop.After using these new object array I want to fill an `UITableView`

`

```
 for(int i=0;i<[matubleArray count];i++)
 {
  //create a new instance from the class
  //assign each values from mutable array to new object's properties
  //add that new object to another mutable array.

 }
```

in order to do this, I don't know how to create this instance class. Is it should be singleton? If its not singleton how to create that class.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it should not be a singleton.  You should create your `NSObject`-derived class like any other object:

```
MyCustomClass *myClass = [MyCustomClass new];
```

and then start populating it (via `@property` accessors) from the JSON data (this assumes an array of dictionary objects, which is not uncommon):

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < [jsonData count]; i++)
{
    MyCustomClass *myClass = [MyCustomClass new];
    NSDictionary *dict = [jsonData objectAtIndex:i];
    myClass.name = [dict objectForValue:@"Name"];
    myClass.age = [[dict objectForValue:"@"Age"] unsignedValue];
    [someOtherArray addObject:myClass];
}
```

So your custom class can be as simple as:

```
@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) unsigned age;

@end
```

Of course things get interesting when holding more complex objects like dates, and you should use an `NSDate` object to hold these and provide a string-to-date conversion method:

```
@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *dateOfBirth;

- (void)setDateOfBirthFromString:(NSString *)str;

@end
```

With the conversion method something like this:

```
- (void)setDateOfBirthFromString:(NSString *)str {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    self.dateOfBirth = [dateFormat dateFromString:str]; 
}
```